# How to accumulate sum by row per column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I would like to do a rowsum (acumulate) per column in the same row. What I spect is something lik this:

```
test = data.frame(c(0,1,1,1,0,0),c(0,0,1,1,1,0),c(0,0,0,1,1,1),c(0,0,0,0,1,1),c(0,0,0,0,0,1))
colnames(test) = c('Position','Position1','Position2','Position3','Position4')
> test
  Position Position1 Position2 Position3 Position4
1        0         0         0         0         0
2        1         0         0         0         0
3        1         1         0         0         0
4        1         1         1         0         0
5        0         1         1         1         0
6        0         0         1         1         1

result = data.frame(c(0,1,2,3,0,0),c(0,0,1,2,3,0),c(0,0,0,1,2,3),c(0,0,0,0,1,2),c(0,0,0,0,0,1))
colnames(result) = c('Position','Position1','Position2','Position3','Position4')
> result
  Position Position1 Position2 Position3 Position4
1        0         0         0         0         0
2        1         0         0         0         0
3        2         1         0         0         0
4        3         2         1         0         0
5        0         3         2         1         0
6        0         0         3         2         1
```

The data.frame result is what I want.

Thanks

Comment: If your problem got solved please [choose an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

At first I thought you just needed to apply `cumsum()` to each column, but it appears you also need to multiply the cumulative sum by the columns themselves to ensure the zeros are preserved:

```r
test = data.frame(c(0,1,1,1,0,0),c(0,0,1,1,1,0),c(0,0,0,1,1,1),c(0,0,0,0,1,1),c(0,0,0,0,0,1))
colnames(test) = c('Position','Position1','Position2','Position3','Position4')
apply(test, 2, function(x) x * cumsum(x))
#>      Position Position1 Position2 Position3 Position4
#> [1,]        0         0         0         0         0
#> [2,]        1         0         0         0         0
#> [3,]        2         1         0         0         0
#> [4,]        3         2         1         0         0
#> [5,]        0         3         2         1         0
#> [6,]        0         0         3         2         1
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

If you truly just want a cumulative sum for each column, you can just use `apply(df, 2, cumsum)`:

```r
test = data.frame(c(0,1,1,1,0,0),c(0,0,1,1,1,0),c(0,0,0,1,1,1),c(0,0,0,0,1,1),c(0,0,0,0,0,1))
colnames(test) = c('Position','Position1','Position2','Position3','Position4')
apply(test, 2, cumsum)
#>      Position Position1 Position2 Position3 Position4
#> [1,]        0         0         0         0         0
#> [2,]        1         0         0         0         0
#> [3,]        2         1         0         0         0
#> [4,]        3         2         1         0         0
#> [5,]        3         3         2         1         0
#> [6,]        3         3         3         2         1
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As a similar alternative to @duckmayr

```
apply(test, 2, function(x) {x[x] <- 1:sum(x); x})

#     Position Position1 Position2 Position3 Position4
#[1,]        0         0         0         0         0
#[2,]        1         0         0         0         0
#[3,]        2         1         0         0         0
#[4,]        3         2         1         0         0
#[5,]        0         3         2         1         0
#[6,]        0         0         3         2         1
```

---

further detail:

```
{        
x[x] <-  # this is a special case because you want to replace the ones. 1 = TRUE in R internally. So you assign values where x == 1. More general would be to write x[x == 1]
1:sum(x) # 1:N makes a sequence from 1, 2, 3, ..., N. sum(x) will return the amount of ones in a col. Again, more general would be `sum(x == 1)`.
; x      # This part is similar to return(x), We want to return the changes we made in x.
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the solution?

Comment: sure,what part you don't understand?

Comment: {x[x == 1] <- 1:sum(x); x}) this one. Thanks

Comment: @AlbertoAguilera I've added a few explanations.